# Joins on One to Many relationships with 3 tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, ssms

Good afternoon all -

I am struggling with a SSMS query. (SQL Server 2008)

I have three tables I need to join.  Essentially I need data from Table 1 and Table 3, but need to use Table 2 to link all together.

Table 1:
Master ID,
Name

Table 2:
Master ID,
Version ID

Table 3:
Version ID,
Calls

Basically I am trying to look at ALL ROWS of Table 3, and include the NAME of the version from table 1. Everything I'm doing, is giving me a 'multi-part identifier "xxx" could not be bound."

I've tried searching for these kinds of joins, and I'm just so new to this - I'm sorry....  I can't embed the screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish; but it let me put a link to my screenshot.  I'm hoping someone can help me with this join, and then the lightbulb will go on in my brain. Thank you in advance.

[Requested result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDIDi.png)

Comment: What do you want if table3 has a record containing a version number not in table2?  1) Include the record but show a NULL value for the name?  or 2) Exclude the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward whats the issue?

ANSI 92 joins using `inner join` and `on` syntax.  Using what appear to be keys for the tables.

```
SELECT T1.Name, T3.VersionId, T3.Calls
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
 on T1.MasterID = T2.MasterID
INNER JOIN table3 T3
 on T2.VersionId = T3.VersionID
```

T1, T2, and T3 are table aliases.

- The INNER JOIN means we only want records if they exist in both
  tables
- t1 and t2 join on MasterID
- t2 and t3 join on VersionID

Maybe a `right` joins instead of `inner` if table 3 has records with versions not in table2; and your statement about ALL records from table3 is true.  Then a right join would be needed instead of an inner; but in this case some records would not have a name!

Comment: And this helped!    I was only doing a join on one of the tables.  The lightbulb has clicked on!  THANK YOU.

Comment: OH - and I'm sorry this was very simple:  it's just that I'm very new to SQL queries......  I appreciate you dealing with my dumb questions!

Comment: No worries.  Just remember each table has to be joined back in someway.  And sometimes you need multiple join criteria in which case you need to use an `AND` (or more than one AND) to show all the related columns.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT T3.VersionId, T3.calls, T1.name
FROM Table3 T3
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T3.VERSIONID=T2.VERSIONID
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.MASTERID=T2.MASTERID
```